# Serial Communication between two Arduino not working

Tags: arduino, serial, c++

I'm trying to perform a simple communication sending two strings in two char arrays from an Arduino Uno to another one.
My problem is that after the 5th or 6th iteration the two strings will mix.

These below are the codes:

Arduino tx:

```
///Tx//COM3
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(3,2);

char mystr[6] = "Hello"; //String data
char mystr2[10] = "MyFliends"; //String data 2

void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  s.write(mystr,6); //Write the serial data
  s.write('\0'); //'\n'
  //Serial.write("",1);  //space
  s.write(mystr2,10); //'\n'
  s.write('\0');
  delay(1000);
}
```

Arduino rx:

```
///Rx//COM4
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(3,2);

//Storing variables.
char mystr[6]; //Hello_
char mystr2_rx[10]; //MyFliends_
char n1[1]; //'\n'
char n2[1]; //'\n'


void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

char rc;

 if(s.available()) {
      //rc = s.read();  //reading from serial buffer one byte everytime
      //Serial.print("The size of rc is:  "); Serial.println(rc);


      s.readBytes(mystr,7); //Read the serial data and store in var //including space
      //s.readBytes(n1,1); // '\n'
      Serial.println(mystr); //Print data on Serial Monitor
      //Serial.println(n1);  //'\n'
      delay(1000);



      //Serial.print("rc: "); Serial.println(rc);
      s.readBytes(mystr2_rx,11);
      //s.readBytes(n2,1);  //'\n'
      Serial.println(mystr2_rx); //Print data on Serial Monitor
      //Serial.println(n2);
      delay(1000);
      }
}
```

I've tried almost everything (I've added *'\0'*, changed array dimension...) but this communication is not consistent after the 5th iteration.

How can I solve this? Thank You

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Arduino-specific software problem, and not an electrical engineering problem per se; I'd recommend asking on the arduino sister site.

Comment: Does it improve if you remove the delays on the receiving side? The reads should be ‘blocking’ and do the waiting them selves.

Comment: @JakobHalskov I didn't thought that, now it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiving side should not include any delays, as the read functions are blocking and will wait themselves.

So over time the receiver will wait too long and get behind the timing schedule.